# Why Hadoop slave task tracker can't start?

Tags: hadoop

hadoop version: 1.2.1

JDK version :java version "1.8.0_111"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

OS :Linux version 2.6.32-642.el6.x86_64

(mockbuild@worker1.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue May 10 17:27:01 UTC 2016

Here is my `"hadoop-root-tasktracker-hslave01.log";`

```
2018-01-24 17:20:31,539 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2018-01-24 17:20:31,709 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered.
2018-01-24 17:20:31,710 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2018-01-24 17:20:31,710 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: TaskTracker metrics system started
2018-01-24 17:20:32,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library
2018-01-24 17:20:32,402 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered.
2018-01-24 17:20:32,688 INFO org.mortbay.log: Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2018-01-24 17:20:32,803 INFO org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer: Added global filtersafety (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter)
2018-01-24 17:20:32,864 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater: Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2018-01-24 17:20:32,870 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tasktracker with owner as root
2018-01-24 17:20:32,875 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Good mapred local directories are: /usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/data/tmp/mapred/local
2018-01-24 17:20:32,889 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered.
2018-01-24 17:20:32,891 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source TaskTrackerMetrics registered.
2018-01-24 17:20:32,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcDetailedActivityForPort47748 registered.
2018-01-24 17:20:32,912 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source RpcActivityForPort47748 registered.
2018-01-24 17:20:32,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting SocketReader
2018-01-24 17:20:32,915 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2018-01-24 17:20:32,917 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 47748: starting
2018-01-24 17:20:32,918 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 47748: starting
2018-01-24 17:20:32,919 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 1 on 47748: starting
2018-01-24 17:20:32,919 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 2 on 47748: starting
2018-01-24 17:20:32,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker up at: localhost/127.0.0.1:47748
2018-01-24 17:20:32,920 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Starting tracker tracker_hslave01:localhost/127.0.0.1:47748
2018-01-24 17:20:32,924 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 3 on 47748: starting
2018-01-24 17:20:33,053 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:root cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol to name node: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InterTrackerProtocol
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getProtocolVersion(NameNode.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

2018-01-24 17:20:33,054 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol to name node: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InterTrackerProtocol
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getProtocolVersion(NameNode.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1428)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1426)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.$Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:374)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:335)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.waitForProxy(RPC.java:300)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$3.run(TaskTracker.java:908)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initialize(TaskTracker.java:904)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.<init>(TaskTracker.java:1573)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.main(TaskTracker.java:3937)

2018-01-24 17:20:33,059 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down TaskTracker at hslave01/192.168.79.133
************************************************************/
```

some config file :
**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
     <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
     <value>192.168.79.129:8020</value>  
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.79.129:8020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop-1.2.1/data/tmp</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Any reason you're running a Hadoop version that's over 5 years old? Task tracker does not exist in Hadoop 2.x or 3

Comment: In any case, HDFS and the task tracker cannot be running on the same port. Change the XML

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm a new learner,the version of hadoop really confused me, I  just met up the 1.x version,so I used it.Thanks for your suggestion,I'll try it .By the way ,any further suggestion for the  choose of  hadoop?